# What type of bifurcation is this?

Tags: non-linear-systems, bifurcation

Consider the dynamical system

$$
dx/dt = -\cos(r)\sin(x)
$$

Clearly $x=0$ and $x=\pi$ are two fixed points of this system.
The stability of these two fixed points change as r is varied. Starting from $r=0$, the zero fixed point is initially stable but becomes unstable at $r=\pi/2$ and the opposite happens for the other fixed point.

Is this a transcritical bifurcation? I have so far only seen systems where one of the fixed point approaches the other fixed point and their stability switch as they cross each other.

[image: The usually shown bifurcation diagram for a system undergoing transcritical bifurcation]

However in my system, the fixed points remain at the same values of $x$. Only stability changes.
If not transcritical, what type of bifurcation is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: I don't believe the system displays a transcritical bifurcation.

Your stability analysis is correct. For instance, for $r=0$, $\dot{x}$ is simply a negative sine function, so positive $x\approx 0$ values have negative derivatives (and decrease, i.e., move towards zero) and negative values have positive derivatives (so increase and also move towards zero), i.e., $x=x^*=0$ is stable for $r<\pi/2$. See figure below:

[image]

And the system does go through a bifurcation as $r$ is varied — though not one of the simple ones, due to the singular nature of the system at $r=r^*=\pi/2$: For this value of $r$ all points $x\in[0,2\pi]$ are (neutrally stable) fixed points, since the system is simply $dx/dt=0$. That's how I'd sketch its bifurcation diagram:

[image]

It looks like we could say there's a collision on $r^*=\pi/2$ and the fixed points "exchange stabilities — just like in a [transcritical bifurcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcritical_bifurcation), however, I think we have something different here, for two reasons:

**I.** If we check the formal conditions for the system $\dot{x}=f_r(x)$ to go through a transcritical bifurcation (e.g., [Guckenheim & Holmes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387908196) or [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TranscriticalBifurcation.html)), we'll see they are:
\begin{align}
f_r(x)\Bigr|_{\forall r, x=x^*}=0  \tag{equilibria}\\
\frac{\partial f_r}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{r=r^*, x=x^*} = 0  \tag{null eigenvalue}\\
\frac{\partial^2 f_r}{\partial r\partial x}\Bigr|_{r=r^*, x=x^*} \ne 0  \tag{TC1}\\
\frac{\partial^2 f_r}{\partial^2 x}\Bigr|_{r=r^*, x=x^*} \ne 0  \tag{TC2} \label{TC2}
\end{align}
where TC stands for transversality condition. And it's clear that our $f_r(x)$ fails to satisfy \ref{TC2}.

**II.** By changing variables, $r \mapsto -r + \pi/2$, the system becomes $f_r(x)=-\sin(r)\sin(x)$ and $r^*=0$. If we then try to put $f_r(x)$ in a algebraic [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(dynamical_systems)), by Taylor expanding it around $(r^*,x^*)$ we obtain, after a new change of variables $r\mapsto r-r^3/6$,
$$
f_r(x) = rx -r\frac{x^3}{6} +O(5)
$$
which I don't believe can be put in the normal form for the transcritical bifurcation, nor any of the other simple ones:
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= r - x^2 \tag{saddle-node}\\
\dot{x} &= rx - x^2 \tag{transcritical}\\
\dot{x} &= r - x^3 \tag{pitchfork}
\end{align}
Which is perhaps not that surprising, given the system's bifurcation diagram.

Comment: I missed out a negative sign in the equation. Thanks for pointing it out. If not transcritical, does this type of bifurcation have some name to it that I can search for?

Comment: @SnehaSrikanth Not that I know, maybe we could call it transcritical-like? :)

Comment: @SnehaSrikanth I'm now convinced the system doesn't display a transcritical bifurcation, check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear detailed answer! I still want to keep the question open for anyone who might be able to pinpoint what kind of bifurcation this is. I am new to StackExchange.. do I edit this post and change the question or make a new question? I do not want your answer to become irrelevant.

Comment: Hey @SnehaSrikanth, you're welcome. My suggestion would be to add after the phrase "Is this a transcritical bifurcation?" something like "If not, which type of bifurcation is it?". Also, don't forget to upvote answers you consider useful. BTW, I did search for what type this bifurcation should be but couldn't find it out.

Comment: Ok will make that change! I am actually unable to upvote yet (I need 15 reputations for that). I'll surely upvote when I hit 15 reputations :D